# SQL - Choose 4 movies (one which stars one actor and the other 3 where he doesn't participate)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 3 tables:

```
FILMS
id film
1  Gladiator
2  Pulp Fiction
3  Taxi Driver
4  ...

ACTORS
id actor
1 Russell Crowe
2 Robert DeNiro
3 John Travolta
4 Samuel L. Jackson

RELATIONSHIPS
id_film id_actor
1       1
2       3
2       4
3       2
```

Now I'm trying to make a query where by passing an actor's id I would get 4 random movies - One where he participates and three others where he doesn't.

I'm finding it hard to find a solution. Any idea of what would be the better approach?

Answer (score 1):

The canonical way would use `union all`.  The following breaks this out into separate CTEs, just to make the logic very clear:

```
with a_1 as (
      select top 1 r.id_file
      from relationships r
      where r.id_actor = @id_actor
      order by newid()
     ),
     nota_3 as (
      select top 3 r.id_film
      from relationships r
      group by r.id_film
      having sum(case when r.id_actor = @id_actor then 1 else 0 end) = 0
      order by newid()
     )
select * from a_1 union all
select * from nota_3;
```

Answer (score 1):

To my mind the clearest way of expressing the query for non-participation films is with `EXCEPT`, like so:

```
;WITH ParticipationFilms AS (
    SELECT F.id, F.film
    FROM FILMS F INNER JOIN RELATIONSHIPS R ON F.id = R.id_film
    WHERE R.id_actor = @id_actor
    )
, NonParticipationFilms AS (
    SELECT id, film
    FROM FILMS
    EXCEPT
    SELECT id, film
    FROM ParticipationFilms
    )
SELECT TOP (1) * FROM ParticipationFilms ORDER BY NEWID()
UNION ALL
SELECT TOP (3) * FROM NonParticipationFilms ORDER BY NEWID()
;
```